# To justify text in spans within a paragraph

Tags: html, css, justify

I have the following HTML structure with multiple spans within a paragraph:

```
<p><span>Hello</span><span>I</span><span>am</span>... </p>
```

The problem is I cannot justify the text in the paragraph.

`text-align: justify` - doesn't work.

Comment: What do you want the last line of the paragraph to look like - is that to be justified or not?

Comment: yes, justified.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the paragraph a flexbox and use `space-between` to simulate justify.

```css
p {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<p><span>Hello</span><span>I</span><span>am</span></p>
```

Comment: To confirm as I have not heard of/used this property before (don't deal in flex often!); will this work for any resolution? E.g. mobile vs laptop vs pc and all will be available?

Comment: the thing is that the last row of a paragraph which has few words will look ugly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to look like the ordinary sort of justification that you would get on an ordinary paragraph then you can use text-align: justify - putting spaces in with an after pseudo element on each span:

```css
p {
  text-align: justify;
}

span::after {
  content: ' ';
}
```

```html
<p><span>Hello</span><span>I</span><span>am</span><span>Hello</span><span>I</span><span>am</span><span>Hello</span><span>I</span><span>am</span><span>Hello</span><span>I</span><span>am</span><span>Hello</span><span>I</span><span>am</span><span>Hello</span><span>I</span><span>am</span><span>Hello</span><span>I</span><span>am</span><span>Hello</span><span>I</span><span>am</span><span>Hello</span><span>I</span><span>am</span><span>Hello</span><span>I</span><span>am</span><span>Hello</span><span>I</span><span>am</span><span>Hello</span><span>I</span><span>am</span><span>Hello</span><span>I</span><span>am</span><span>Hello</span><span>I</span><span>am</span><span>Hello</span><span>I</span><span>am</span><span>Hello</span><span>I</span><span>am</span><span>Hello</span><span>I</span><span>am</span><span>Hello</span><span>I</span><span>am</span><span>Hello</span><span>I</span><span>am</span><span>Hello</span><span>I</span><span>am</span><span>Hello</span><span>I</span><span>am</span><span>am</span><span>Hello</span><span>I</span><span>am</span><span>Hello</span><span>I</span><span>am</span><span>Hello</span><span>I</span><span>am</span><span>Hello</span><span>I</span><span>am</span>  </p>
```

Comment: wow, that's crazy! works like a magic!